# ng not recognized in powershell

Tags: angular

ng : The term 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ng new abc
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ng:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: thanks it did clarify my doubts....it seems different solutions are working for different people ... in my case angular path was added already to the user variable path...but adding %AppData%\npm this to the system variable path ...worked for me..

Comment: Awesome! Happy coding.